# Trouble forcing browser to treat button click as history traversal event

Tags: javascript, browser-history

I am building a website that is navigated through a series of directional buttons. Right and left clicks move between different images associated with one project. Up and down clicks move between projects.

What I am trying to do is ensure that when a user clicks up or down (i.e. between projects) that this is registered as a history traversal event and that a new entry for the new project is visible within the browser's history.

The code that I have sets an event on the the click of the navigation buttons that makes the necessary changes to the pages content, and then I attempt to push the new page to the history object by calling this function (see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/824349/modify-the-url-without-reloading-the-page) for background information):

```
var pushToHistory = function(url, pageTitle, html) {
    history.pushState({'html':html, 'pageTitle':pageTitle}, '', url); 
}
```

I supply the arguments to this function elsewhere by doing the following after the page has loaded the new content:

```
html = document.getElementsByClassName('main-frame')[0].innerHTML
pageTitle = 'http://mysite/'+newpath;    // new path specifieds the new item. 
this.pushToHistory( url, pageTitle, html);
```

Now the problem I am having is that the result of all of this is that both in Chrome and in Firefox the history is updated in a way that is **mostly** correct: the url in the history's state object is correct, as is this the content. So that if I click on one of these history events, the correct page is retrieved.

However, the page title, which is shown in the list of history items is incorrect. It is always the title of the page that was loaded when the site was intially loaded. So if I load mysite/a-project, and the title of the page is "My Site - A Project" that is always what appears in the box. I have also checked my code to ensure that the pageTitle object is correct, so dumping `pageTitle` before calling `history.pushState()` shows the correct title.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I discovered the problem. I needed to set `document.title` first.  That meant somewhere before I call `history.pushState()`, I needed to do this:

```
document.title = theNewTitle;
```